# ARKit Apply true heading manually to node inside scene

Tags: swift, scenekit, core-location, augmented-reality, arkit

I'm trying to apply device true north heading manually to a node inside ARKit Scene, so it will be similar to gravityAndHeading worldAlignment.

As I understood, I need to take a difference between heading for CoreLocation and pov Y rotation, but all my tries are failed and as a result, node rotation is incorrect and unstable.

Could anyone give advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried from Apple’s coremotion framework the [CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXTrueNorthZVertical](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmattitudereferenceframe/cmattitudereferenceframextruenorthzvertical?language=objc) enum?

It feels like a simple solution, if I missunderstood the question please clarify